# Convert a JSON array into object using dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have below payload with a hierarchy and trying to filter based on the columnn "DeleteIndicator" = "Y". These are the fixed columns I will be getting. I want to traverse through the payload and check for the DeleteIndicator. Updated the input and expected output for multiple child in inner array.

**Input:**

```
    {
   "Num":4363886,
   "LineItems":[
      {
         "DetailGUID":"B439E023360C",
         "DeleteIndicator":"Y"
      },
      {
         "DetailGUID":"B439E023360C",
         "LineQuantity":[
            {
               "AltGUID":"2B43AC4203DC",
               "DeleteIndicator":"Y"
            },
            {
               "AltGUID":"2B43AC4203DD",
               "DeleteIndicator":"Y"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "DetailGUID":"B439E023360C",
         "LineQuantity":[
            {
               "AltGUID":"2B43AC4203DC",
               "ShipTo":[
                  {
                     "ShipToGUID":"2B43AC4201AB",
                     "DeleteIndicator":"Y"
                  },
                  {
                     "ShipToGUID":"2B43AC4201AC",
                     "DeleteIndicator":"Y"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
   "Num":4363886,
   "Details":[
      {
         "DetailGUID":"B439E023360C",
         "AltGUID":null,
         "ShipToGUID":null
      },
      {
         "DetailGUID":"B439E023360C",
         "AltGUID":"2B43AC4203DC",
         "ShipToGUID":null
      },
      {
         "DetailGUID":"B439E023360C",
         "AltGUID":"2B43AC4203DD",
         "ShipToGUID":null
      },
      {
         "DetailGUID":"B439E023360C",
         "AltGUID":"2B43AC4203DC",
         "ShipToGUID":"2B43AC4201AB"
      },
      {
         "DetailGUID":"B439E023360C",
         "AltGUID":"2B43AC4203DC",
         "ShipToGUID":"2B43AC4201AC"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get your work done.Please let me know if you need any  clarifications.

```
    %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
Num:payload.Num,
Details:payload.LineItems map (v0,k0) ->
{
    DetailGUID:v0..DetailGUID[0],
    AltGUID:v0..AltGUID[0],
    ShipToGUID:v0..ShipToGUID[0]
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. this worked. But I just realized there can be multiple childs at the LineQuantity and ShipTo. In that case how to handle? I have updated my original input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a little complicated, but I have tried my best to make the code readable and documented.
Try to look at the problem from a different angle. Think that you are trying to "spread" the fields of "LineItems" across all the "LineQuantity".

```
%dw 2.0

// This Function takes a json and an array and spreads the json fields
// across each elements of the array.
fun spreadAcrossArray(json: Object, array: Array | Null) = (array default [{}]) map {
    (json),
    ($)
}

//Here is the main logic of getting the payload.
//The idea is first to "Spread" the lineItem Elements across all the "LineQuantity" 
//and then spread those to all "ShipTo" elements. 
fun spreadLineItemAcrossLineQuantity(lineItems: Array) = lineItems map ((lineItem) -> do {
     var lineItemSpreadedAcrossQuantity = 
        {DetailGUID: lineItem.DetailGUID} spreadAcrossArray lineItem.LineQuantity
     ---
     flatten(lineItemSpreadedAcrossQuantity map ({
            DetailGUID: $.DetailGUID,
            AltGUID: $.AltGUID
        } spreadAcrossArray $.ShipTo)) //Map app the lineItemSpreadedAcrossQuantity with spreading them to lineItemSpreadedAcrossQuantity.ShipTo
    }
)

output application/json
---
{
    Num: payload.Num,
    Details: flatten(spreadLineItemAcrossLineQuantity(payload.LineItems))
    map {
        DetailGUID: $.DetailGUID,
        AltGUID: $.AltGUID,
        ShipToGUID: $.ShipToGUID
    }
}
```

It requires the array to be flattened later because you are basically passing an Object in the `spreadAcrossArray` function and in return you are getting an array. And the map function is also returning an array and so you are getting an array of arrays.